# Regex stopping at first match, I don't want it to

Tags: php, match

This is happening in multiple places, but here is an example. I am trying to grab name servers from `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 2.2.2.2
```

Here is my regex, it works for only the first match. Why can I not match ALL nameservers here? My `$match` array only has ne value.

`preg_match('/nameserver ([^\s]+)/', $fileContents, $match);`

Thanks for reading.

Comment: pssst… `preg_match_all()` … pssst…

Comment: heh...here I am thinking my regex is messed up :/

thanks by the way